# How do I process single elements inside a flat_map?

Tags: enums, rust

Is it possible to handle different numbers of elements inside a `flat_map` in Rust?

I have a case where based on a condition I need to either map a single `enum` element or a vector of `enum` elements.

I tried to use `std::iter::once` but it's not working since `once` and `Vec::iter` are different types the could not be returned from the same `if` condition.

```rust
enum Enum {
    Ident(String),
    Val(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let my_vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let condition = true; // Any condition

    my_vec
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|x| {
            if condition {
                std::iter::once(Enum::Ident("id".to_string())).into_iter() /* single Enum element */
            } else {
                vec![Enum::Val(1), Enum::Val(2)].iter() /* vector of Enum elements */
            }
        })
        .collect::<Vec<Enum>>()
}
```

```
error[E0308]: `if` and `else` have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:16:17
   |
13 | /             if condition {
14 | |                 std::iter::once(Enum::Ident("id".to_string())).into_iter() /* single Enum element */
   | |                 ---------------------------------------------------------- expected because of this
15 | |             } else {
16 | |                 vec![Enum::Val(1), Enum::Val(2)].iter() /* vector of Enum elements */
   | |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::iter::Once`, found struct `std::slice::Iter`
17 | |             }
   | |_____________- `if` and `else` have incompatible types
   |
   = note: expected type `std::iter::Once<Enum>`
            found struct `std::slice::Iter<'_, Enum>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious solution is to use a vector in both cases:

```
my_vec
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|_| {
        if condition {
            vec![Enum::Ident("id".to_string())].into_iter()
        } else {
            vec![Enum::Val(1), Enum::Val(2)].into_iter()
        }
    })
    .collect::<Vec<Enum>>();
```

This will cause an additional allocation for the one-element vector, but it is a simple and readable solution. If you want to avoid this overhead, one option is to use the `either` crate:

```
use either::{Left, Right};

enum Enum {
    Ident(String),
    Val(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let my_vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let _ = my_vec
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|&x| {
            if x > 1 {
                Left(std::iter::once(Enum::Ident("id".to_string())))
            } else {
                Right(vec![Enum::Val(1), Enum::Val(2)].into_iter())
            }
        })
        .collect::<Vec<Enum>>();
}
```

The crate defines a generic enum `Either` with the variants `Left` and `Right`. If the types of both side support iteration, the enum also supports iterations by dispatching to the respective underlying iterator types.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without allocating a vector for a single element? Maybe somehow turning it into iterator?

Comment: Please see the latest version of the answer.

Comment: The `either` solution looks just like what I need. Is there a similar solution for a `match` clause (in the case of more than 2 branches) ?

Comment: @Ivan I'm not aware of one. You can search for one yourself, but it's probably better to write your own enum in that case – it will probably make your code more readable. That said, it's unlikely the additional allocation matters – it hardly ever does, so please consider that solution as well.